# Seeing own posts that have been flagged in the 10k tools

Tags: discussion, flags, 10k-tools, original-poster

I was able to see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429245/find-if-a-string-is-not-part-of-a-list-of-list-in-python/18429286#18429286), which has been flagged as not an answer, while going through the review tools. Is this supposed to be possible, or is this a glitch? If it's meant to be possible - what's the point of it? Surely being the OP I'm going to be biased and most likely wish to choose to disagree with the flags...

[image: Example]

**update:**

I've been able to select "flag or disagree" and then say "I disagree"...

So, would there be some gaming involved here, if I was to agree with the flag, then delete my own answer (would I get a helpful flag for that), then undelete it (still leave my answer there)...?

However, as expected, it now appears to have disappeared from the queue as expected (or at least I assume it has, as it hasn't appeared in the 50 from multiple page reloads anyway...)

And here it is in flag history:

[image: History example]

Comment: maybe you could also flag your own post and dospute own flag? to make a _perfect solo_ so to speak? I feel a new badge coming, awarded to users who managed to 1) post, 2) flag their own post, 3) dispute their own flag on their own post, 4) raise a meta discussion about own dispute of own flag cast on their own post. [Solipsist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solipsism)?

Comment: @gnat does one get bonus points for accepting their own answer on top? (and then flagging their own answer...)

Comment: I am not sure this is a huge problem. The flags in the 10k queue change the prioritizing of items, but not much else. So, if you dispute it, enough others will still agree with the flag and drown out the dispute.

Comment: @Emracool I'm not sure it's a massive problem either - however, I'd like to know if it's by design. I can't vote on my own questions/answers for instance, but I can dispute flags on them? And AFAIK, what could be deemed helpful flags end up as disputed if I dispute them.... etc.... Seems inconsistent...