# Why can I invalid flag my own flagged answer?

Tags: bug, flags

I responded to a question with a rather sarcastic answer which was flagged as not an answer. Now for some reason I was able to review my own flagged answer and set an invalid flag.

Is it normal that I can invalid flag my own answers? This kind of defeats the purpose of peer review no?

Comment: The peer review process isn't obstructed though, posts are usually handled with at least 5 flags as far as I can see.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to do this.  I generally put a great amount of weight on flag disputes when moderating, and if you can do this on your own post, it throws that whole process into doubt.  Granted, I suppose I can check the name on the flag against the name on the post, but that's just one more thing to do.

Comment: Strongly related: [Seeing own posts that have been flagged in the 10k tools](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194623/seeing-own-posts-that-have-been-flagged-in-the-10k-tools) (but I realised this was about the review queue, I think?)

Comment: I think it's a duplicate @Tim. You can't invalid flag from the review queue and Jon demonstrates that he managed to invalid flag a flag on his post in the linked question.